# How to import bookmarks into Tor browser from other browsers?

Tags: configuration

How do I import bookmarks into Tor Browser from other browsers? The Tor Browser version I am using is 9.0.1.

Comment: Keep in mind that it doesn't matter one bit to use the Tor Browser if you will be visiting websites with identifiable, unique parameters or URLs. E.g. if you bookmark a URL that has your customer ID as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Export bookmarks from previous browser as an HTML file.

In Tor Browser CTRL-SHIFT-O (That's O not zero). Click on "Import and Backup" > Import Bookmarks from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Either from a backup like @JSEvans said - or via any export/import plugin of your choice, but the mechanics is basically the same. Unless you need something like a private cloud for that